# How do you access the length of the array inside of this object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 507351805725f3457b000055,
    audioFiles: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

I want to access the length property of audioFiles so that I can loop through its contents.  However I keep getting undefined or 1.  Can someone tell me the correct way?

Here's what I've tried so far (note that the object variable is named audios).

```
audios.audioFiles.length
audios.length
audios[0].audioFiles.length
```

Comment: `audios[0].audioFiles.length` should work; if it doesn't, then your object doesn't really look like that.

Comment: Argh, you're right...very embarrassed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

```
> audios[0].audioFiles.length
2
```

You can test this for yourself using Chrome's Web Inspector or Firebug on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`audios[0].audioFiles.length`